# Go to to next error/warning codes in a file in Xcode

Tags: xcode

In Android Studio, if a file has some error, we could easily go to the error within the file by pressing F2 function key.

What is the relevant key in Xcode (10.1)? Command+' and Command+" is not helping as it open up some dialog box instead of going to the Error Line within the file.

Comment: "Open up some dialog box"...? The shortcuts you mentioned cycle through all issues of your project (not only the current file), for issues in the file, there are small indicators in the right gutter (yellow for warnings, red for errors) that you can click.

Comment: I have a code that is compilable and executed well on the simulator. Then by making a simple typo error, and move up to the top of the file, there's a red line appear in the file (showing there's an error in the file). So I use `command+'` and `command+"`. Instead of going to that error, it just open up another dialog (perhaps some warning of setting that is not that important to be fix). I expect it to bring me to the compile error line but it didn't.

Comment: What does the dialog box say?

Comment: Build Settings, target build settings, Enable Recommended Warnings,  Build Optimization...

Comment: You are pressing Command-dot by the sound of it.

Comment: No. It is `Jump to Next Issue` command. I use the Menu bar and click on it. The same thing happens.